# What might be the half-life of observationally stable nuclei with energetically favorable decay modes?

Tags: nuclear-physics, radioactivity, elements, half-life

For example, a reaction

$${}^{132} \mathrm{Ba} \rightarrow {}^{128}\mathrm{Xe} + \alpha + 22.19\mathrm{keV}$$

would be energetically favorable, contrary that ${}^{132} \mathrm{Ba}$ is observationally stable. However, energetically favorable reactions happen, only not very quickly. There are also a lot of similar examples.

Does any estimation exist, what could be its half-life? How could it be calculated? I think, it might depend on some potential gate calculation.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is the empirically found [Geiger-Nuttall law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geiger%E2%80%93Nuttall_law)
relating the energy of the $\alpha$ decay to its half-life:

> $$\log T_{1/2} = \frac{A(Z)}{\sqrt{E}}+B(Z)$$
> where $T_{1/2}$ is the half-life, $E$ the total kinetic energy
> (of the alpha particle and the daughter nucleus), and $A$ and $B$
> are coefficients that depend on the isotope's atomic number $Z$.

[image]
<sub>(image from [this question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/163023/how-to-apply-the-geiger-nuttall-rule-to-find-half-life))</sub>

You see, for decay energy less than $4$ MeV the half-life is
longer than $10^{18}$ s ($\approx 10^{11}$ years),
so that such a decay is hard to observe because it would require
a very large number of atoms.

Comment: It's not *impossible* to observe decays whose mean life is longer than the age of the universe, so long as you have enough of the isotope. An example is xenon-124, a $\beta\beta\nu\nu$ emitter with half life $10^{22}$ years. But it takes some luck and some skill. Alpha decays don't currently have the discovery potential that double beta decays have, so there is less reason to look. Furthermore, barium (unlike xenon) doesn't turn into a liquid scintillator at any convenient temperature or pressure, so you can't use the trick of having your sources and your detector being the same object.

Comment: Afaik proton decay is tried to be found on samples with $\ge 10^{30}$ protons. That is because, even if you can not watch a proton $10^{35}$  years long, we can watch $10^{35}$ protons 1 year long. Having 1 mol (132g) Ba132 will result $\approx$ 200 Xe decays in a year, and that looks for me observable with today technology.

Comment: @peterh + rob: You are right. I have modified my statement.

Answer (score 2):

Well according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isotopes_of_barium#cite_note-15), it's estimated to have a half life of over $3 \times 10^{20}$ years.

According to [periodictable.com](https://periodictable.com/Isotopes/056.132/index.html) it has a half life of $3 \times 10^{21}$ years; and according to [buyisotope.com](https://www.buyisotope.com/barium-132-isotope.php) it also has a half life of $3 \times 10^{21}$ years.